# Don't know how to make script with preloaded images

Tags: javascript, image, image-preloader

Can someone look over this and tell me what I have to do to get the images to show up?

```
<head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">



<!-- //Begin

function changeImage(filename)
{
  mainimage.src = filename;
}

//  End -->
</script>

</head>



<body>

<p>
<a href="javascript:changeImage('image-viewer/image1.jpg')">Image 1</a>
<a href="javascript:changeImage('image-viewer/image2.jpg')">Image 2</a>
<a href="javascript:changeImage('image-viewer/image3.jpg')">Image 3</a>
<a href="javascript:changeImage('image-viewer/image4.jpg')">Image 4</a>
</p>
<p>
<img name="mainimage" src="image-viewer/blank.jpg"></p>


<p><center>
<font face="arial, helvetica" size"-2">
</center><p>


</script>
</font></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your current code seems to work fine. I made a copy of your code, put it in a file called test.html, then made a folder called "image-viewer" and put 4 images in there. And it worked in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. Can't test on IE on my home computer. Are you sure you've got the file names correct?

Comment: I don't know how to load the images onto my page. I know this sounds ridiculous, but when you run the script, no pictures show up. Are the pictures supposed to come from my computer?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, however it doesn't load with IE. That's my issue.

Comment: Should I have a blank.jpg in my image-viewer file as well?

Comment: Please don't use javascript: URLs - they break horribly if link is opened in new tab (which I do often). `<a href="image.jpg" onclick="changeImage(this.href);return false">` will do the same thing, better.

Comment: Yes, that works. However I want to be able to change images on the same page rather than having to go back and click on the next link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample page</title>   
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeImage(replacement)
        {
            document.getElementById("main_image").src = replacement;
            return false;   
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:changeImage('image1.jpg')">Image 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:changeImage('image2.jpg')">Image 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:changeImage('image3.jpg')">Image 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:changeImage('image4.jpg')">Image 4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            <img id="main_image" src="image-viewer/blank.jpg" alt="" />
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to:

```
function changeImage(filename) {
  document.main_image.src=filename;
  void(0);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to sound ignorant, however my images still will not show up when I run the script. All that pops up is the red "X" in a white box.

Comment: How do I get the pictures loaded onto my page?

Comment: Sorry... I messed up, it wasn't an ID, but name. I've changed my code accordingly. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

A good friend helped me look this up

`mainimage.src = filename;` is wrong, and should instead be

`<img name="mainimage" src="image-viewer/blank.jpg">`

should be

`<img id ="mainimage" src="image-viewer/blank.jpg">`

And then this:

`mainimage.src = filename;`

should be

`document.getElementById("mainimage").setAttribute("src", filename);`

there's an extra 
tag in the end.

I think she's having more of a problem with her image locations, though.  He needs more info about project

**Edit** : What might be happening
is she has the html file
in the same folder
as the images
which really won't work.
because if all her files are in
c:/image-viewer/
with no subdirectories
and the html file is   `c:/image-viewer/index.html`. Therefore she needs a new folder for the images

Because the script
is asking for
c:/image-viewer/image-viewer/image1.jpg
as opposed to c:/image-viewer/image1.jpg

If this isn't for a class, she needs to learn to write standards compliant code. Look up DOM

if all the files are in one folder, then she has to do away with `image-viewer/` in front of the file names.